# Electron + xmpp.js: How I can Debug SSL Self-signed error messages?

Tags: javascript, electron, xmpp, node-xmpp

I am using a combination of electron.js and xmpp.js in order to make my own client. My main project is consisted of these 2 files:

Boostrapping electron on: `index.js`:

```
const {app,BrowserWindow,ipcMain,dialog}=require('electron');
// const app=electron.app;
// const BrowserWindow=electron.BrowserWindow;

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  console.log("Message");
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/ui/index.html`);
  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

  if(env==='dev'){
    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  mainWindow.maximize();

  const xmpp=require('./xmpp.js');
  console.log(xmpp)
  xmpp.xmppCli(mainWindow,ipcMain,dialog);
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

And handling it with this file `xmpp.js`:

```
const {client, xml, jid} = require('@xmpp/client')

var clientInstance=null;

console.log('xmpp.js loaded')

const initXmpp= function(xmpp){

  xmpp.on('error', err => {
    console.error("Error occured",err.toString())
    dialog.showErrorBox('Internal Error',err.toString())
  })

  xmpp.on('offline', () => {
    console.log('', 'offline')
  })

  xmpp.on('online', async address => {
    dialog.showMessageBox({'type':'info','message':"Online as:"+address.toString()})
  })

  xmpp.on('stanza', stanza => {
    console.log('⮈', stanza.toString())
    xmpp.stop()
  })

  process.on('unhandledRejection', function (reason, p) {
    console.log('Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', p, ' reason: ', reason)
  })

  xmpp.start()
}

module.exports.xmppCli=function(mainWindow,ipcMain,dialog){


  ipcMain.on('login',(event,params)=>{
    let jidVal=jid(params.username);
    params.server="xmpp://"+params.server
    console.log(jidVal.getLocal(),jidVal.getDomain(),params.server)

    if(!clientInstance){
      console.log("Client Works");
      try{
          clientInstance=new client({
            'service':params.server,
            'domain': jidVal.getDomain(),
            'username':jidVal.getLocal(),
            'password':params.password,
          })
          initXmpp(clientInstance)
      } catch(e) {
        console.error('Internal Error',e.message)
        console.error(e.stack)
        clientInstance=null;
      }
    }

  });
}
```

Also my ui is consisted by `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css">
    <style>
      html, body, .container-fluid {
          height: 100%;
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      }

      #form_wrapper{
          border:1px solid;
          border-radius: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index_renderer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-secondary">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div id="form_wrapper" class="p-2" style="background-color:white;">
          <h1 class="text-center">XMPP KEY AGREEMENT CLI</h1>
          <form id="loginForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="server">XMPP Server</label>
              <input id="server" class="form-control" type="text" name="server" placeholder="eg. example.com" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="eg. user@example.com" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input id="password" class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Type your password here" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the following renderer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

  $("#loginForm").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/29000408/4706711
    let data=$(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(a, x) { a[x.name] = x.value; return a; }, {});
    ipcRenderer.send('login',data)
  })

})
```

But my problem is that when I fired up my own local opefireserver using self-signed certificates. Because of that I get a mysterious error that is displayed like that:

[image: Error Shown]

So my problems are:

- How I can debug these types of errors? I mean I cannot find out the location of this error.
- How I can manually tell either to electron or xmpp.js manually to accept self-signed certificates>

I tried to manually figure out where this error is generated via changing:

```
  xmpp.on('error', err => {
    console.error("Error occured",err.toString())
    dialog.showErrorBox('Internal Error',err.toString())
  })
```

Into this:

```
  xmpp.on('error', err => {
    console.error("Error occured",err.toString())
  })
```

Still getting strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@xmpp/client` library seems that lacks the api calls when connection error happens as seen in the following example:

```
const {client, xml, jid} = require('@xmpp/client')

const initXmpp=function(xmpp){

  xmpp.on('error', err => {
    console.error("Error occured",err.toString())
    // dialog.showErrorBox('Internal Error',err.toString())
  })

  xmpp.on('offline', () => {
    console.log('', 'offline')
  })

  xmpp.on('online', async address => {
    dialog.showMessageBox({'type':'info','message':"Online as:"+address.toString()})
  })

  xmpp.on('stanza', stanza => {
    console.log('⮈', stanza.toString())
    xmpp.stop()
  })

  process.on('unhandledRejection', function (reason, p) {
    console.error('Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', p, ' reason: ', reason)
  })

  try{
    xmpp.start()
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message)
  }
}

try{
  clientInstance=new client({
    'service':"xmpp://0.0.0.0:5222",
    'domain': "example.com",
    'username':"admin",
    'password':"admin",
  });

  initXmpp(clientInstance);
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

That I get the following error:

```
 events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)
```

And offers no way to handle it, that is because the SSL/TLS connections are handled by the nodejs itself thus the only solution can be found on this gthub [answer](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/issues/598#issuecomment-441139677).

Based on the solution mentioned above actually combined with `NODE_ENV` environmental variable I placed the following code snippet on `index.js`:

```
if(env==='dev' || env=='debug'){
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0;
}
```

Also if using [this](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-openfire) I would suggest to fork it and modify it to use latest version of ubuntu (or even a more stable docker image) and later version of openfire such as [this](https://github.com/pc-magas/docker-openfire) guy did.